# Codename one uwp build failed

Tags: codenameone

until yesterday everything was fine, I could build my UWP app and download it from the build server.

From today, without changing anything I get an error:

```
 [exec]   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
 [exec] src\com\codename1\admob\AdMobNativeImplFactoryImpl.cs(6,20): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'com.codename1.admob.AdMobNativeImpl' to 'com.codename1.admob.IAdMobNativeImpl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [C:\Users\CODENA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8891191631952326639xxx\TestProject\UWPProject\UWPApp\UWPApp.csproj]
 [exec] Done Building Project "C:\Users\CODENA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8891191631952326639xxx\TestProject\UWPProject\UWPApp\UWPApp.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 [exec] 
 [exec] Build FAILED.
 [exec] 
 [exec] "C:\Users\CODENA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8891191631952326639xxx\TestProject\UWPProject\UWPApp\UWPApp.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
 [exec] (XamlPreCompile target) -> 
 [exec]   src\com\codename1\admob\AdMobNativeImplFactoryImpl.cs(6,20): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'com.codename1.admob.AdMobNativeImpl' to 'com.codename1.admob.IAdMobNativeImpl'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [C:\Users\CODENA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8891191631952326639xxx\TestProject\UWPProject\UWPApp\UWPApp.csproj]
 [exec] 
 [exec]     0 Warning(s)
 [exec]     1 Error(s)
 [exec] 
 [exec] Time Elapsed 00:00:04.94

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\CODENA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8891191631952326639xxx\TestProject\build-win.xml:64: exec returned: 1
```

does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

We released an update that added support for native interfaces for UWP which might have failed for some older stub code generated for the previous Windows versions.

I'm assuming you are using the full screen admob cn1lib?

Please file an issue or a pull request to fix this. We can probably fix it some time next week, if you want it now these are the steps to do the fix yourself:

1. Checkout the cn1lib sources from github
2. Delete the files under `native/windows`
3. Open the project in NetBeans
4. Find the interfaces implementing `NativeInterface`
5. Right click them and select Generate Native Sources: **IMPORTANT** answer **NO** to overwriting existing code
6. Build and install the library

Extra credit:

Commit the change and submit a pull request for that and ideally fork http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/ and submit the updated library there.